# How to make generic type with higher order component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Lets say I have component like that:

```
const Input = <TFormData,>(props: InputProps) => {
   return <Field<TFormData>...</Field> // here I need to pass generic type to Field
}
```

and calling him like:

```
<Input<{name: string}> />
```

now I would like to add functionality of forwardingRef (or any other HOC) so I tried something like:

```
const Input = <TFormData,>forwardRef<HTMLElement, InputProps>((props, ref) => { // ts throws error
   return <Field<TFormData>...</Field>
})
```

and call it in the same way. But it seems it is not valid syntax. How to deal with that?

Comment: Your syntax looks off. Can you provide a code sandbox link or a full demo to work with?